What is the definition of balance when engineering structures?
In the comment section of a YouTube short comparing engineers and architects (in a lighthearted manner) someone made the claim that any two objects secured together and are not moving are in balance from a structural engineering perspective. I would like to know if that is an accurate definition.
Here is a simplified example of what was being discussed.
If a bar positioned vertically was imbedded in the ground and a horizontal bar was positioned so one third of it was on one side of the vertical bar and two thirds of it was on the other side and the two bars were secured together, would that be an example of balance?
YouTube clip
Here is a screen shot from the clip

I searched for the definition of balance in engineering and mostly found the comparison of static vs dynamic balance.
I don't know what the best tag would be for this question so I guessed.

This question seems to be missing context. Generally there is no such thing as engineering as a whole. Engineering has many subfields and many subcultures.

I edited the title of the post. Does that give it greater clarity?

Is it possible that by "balance", they actually meant static equilibrium? (which can be described using balanced forces)

@TomášLétal I added an image from a video and a link to the video. From my perspective they were not talking about static equilibrium, but I never studied engineering, only physics.

I don't think balance is a clearly defined technical term in structural engineering, but that is just my guess.

I have never heard of the word "balance" applied to engineering other than not falling down in the shop.

How does this in any way signify that balance is a term in engineering? Its a comment on how engineers and architects think. Architects try to find beauty and meaning in what they do so they will modify the brief to suit themselves. Engineers tend to solve the problems efficiently with minimum effort and cost, if you wanted it to be beautiful and symmetrical it should have been in the brief.  Its a jest on the fact that the word balance does not mean the same things in all contexts.
